# circular text field in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a requirement from my client in which I need to implement a **circular** `TextField` *(not just rounded corners)* and when any user enter text via keyboard, it should display that text circularly so how I'll be able to do that? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps a photoshopped example would help?

Comment: @sam can u show screen shot which type of the text filed u need

Comment: There might be several solutions for this description. If it is a client you should also have some requirements and within them also a design, show it to us

Comment: Override the draw rect. See my answer:

Comment: @亚历山大 not all clients provide designs, they will just provide a description of what they want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetAlpha(context, 1.0);
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, CGRectMake(0,0,self.frame.size.width,self.frame.size.height));

    [super drawRect:rect];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a circular `UIView` and add a transparent "textfield" as a "subview". Alternatively, you can add a `UIImageView` that matches your specification with the requested image - or more concisely, set the "backgroundImage" property of the "textfield" itself.

Comment: Sorry but I don't think this will solved there issue, I think a mix of both `CW0007007` and `manujmv` answers would be best.

Comment: i think it is hard to know seeing that his question was quite vague.

Comment: It's not vague at all, display a circular `UITextField`. What is vague about that?